Redirect to Area Controller
I'm trying to redirect from a non-area controller to an area controller.
I tried this - attempt #1:
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account", new { areas = "AccountArea" });

Attempt #2:
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "account",
    areaName:"AccountArea",
    pattern: "AccountArea/{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

return RedirectToRoute("account");

My folder structure is


Can you post your Default Route configuration +  your error details?

it should be new { area = "AccountArea" }  not "areas" for RedirectToAction. If that doesn't work, make sure your AccountController doesn't have any custom routing attributes or such that override the default mapping.

As already said, you used areas = "AccountArea", which is incorrect because the correct route parameter for an area is area (not areas). So you should write return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account", new { area = "AccountArea" });

Firstly use "area=" instead of "areas=". Then make sure the area page can be reached
    [Area("AccountArea")]
    public class AccountController : Controller

Last important thing is put the "area" route template in front of the default template.
app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Then this redirection will work.
